# copy a list and return the pointer, pointing to the second list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I toned up my simple app which allows you to work with linked lists. each node has a char value as data and an int count which counts the occurrence of each data.
I need a function to copy the existing list and paste it somewhere else and finally return the address of the first node of the pasted list. how can I do that?
here's my whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Snode //Snode class defines a node in a list
{
    char data;
    int count = 1;
    Snode *next = NULL;
    Snode(char a) : data(a) {}
};

class set//set class defines the list
{
private:
    Snode *head;
public:
    set() : head(NULL)//constructor method of the list
    {
        Snode *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            Snode *next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = next;
        }
        head = NULL;
    }
    ~set()//destructor method of the list
    {
        Snode *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
    bool isAvailable(char value)//checks if the node is already in the list or not
    {
        Snode *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)//untill the end of the list
        {
            if (temp->data == value)//if a similar node is found
                return true;
            else//if temp is not equal check the next node
                temp = temp->next;
        }
        return false;//if no node is found return false
    }

    bool isFirst(char value)//checks if the node is the first node or not
    {
        return(head->data == value);//if it equals to head, it's the first node
    }

    bool isLast(char value)//checks if the node is the last node or not
    {
        Snode *last ;
        return(last->next = NULL);//if its next pointer points the null pointer, it's the last node in the list
    }


    void display()//showing all the nodes
    {
        //creating a variable node to travers available nodes
        Snode *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)//travers nodes untill the end of the list
        {
            cout << temp->data << " " << temp->count << "\n"; //output format
            temp = temp->next;//setting the next node as the variable
        }
    }

    void insert(char value)//inserts a new node
    {
        if (head == NULL)//if the list is empty
        {
            //create a new node, set its count to 1 and set it as head of the list
            Snode *temp = new Snode(value);
            temp->count = 1;
            head = temp;
        }
        else//is the list is'nt empty
        { 
            if (isAvailable(value))//if the value is already available
                {
                    //find the existing node and increase its count by 1
                    Snode *temp = head;
                    while (temp->data != value)//check the list to the end
                        temp = temp->next;
                    temp->count += 1;
                }
            else//if there's not an existing node with the given value
            {
                //create a new node with a count of 1 at the end of the list by setting *next equal to NULL
                Snode *temp = new Snode(value);
                temp->count = 1;
                temp->next = NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    int count(char value)//counts the occurrence of a character value by reading the same node's count
    {
        Snode *temp = head;
            while (temp != NULL)//travers nodes untill the end of the list
            {
                if(temp->data==value)
                {
                    cout<<temp->count;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"This character is not in the list";
                }
            }
        return temp->count;
    }

    void deleteFirst(char value)//delete the first node in the list
{
    Snode *temp = head;//create a new node including head's data
    head = head->next;//setting the second node as head
    delete temp;//deleting the first node
}
void deleteLast(char value)//deleting the last node in the list
{
    Snode *current= new head;//creating two new nodes and starting the travers from the first node
    Snode *previous=new Snode();
    while(current->next!=NULL)//continue traversing untill the end of the list
    {
      previous=current;//moving current and previous nodes to the right in order to check the next nodes
      current=current->next;
      if(current->next == NULL)//if the list is finished
      {
          previous->next = NULL;//pointing the previous node's next as NULL, instead of the last node
          delete current;//deleting the last node
      }
    }
}

char remove(char value, struct Snode *temp)//removing a node from the list
{
    if(!isAvailable(value))//if there's no node with the given data
    {

        cout<<"Not available";
        return NULL;
    }

    else//if there is already a node with the same data
    {
        if(temp->count == 1)//if there's a node with one time occurrence
        {
            if(isFirst(value)//if it's equal to the first node
            {
                deleteFirst(value);
            }
            else if(isLast(value))//if it's equal to the last node
            {
                deleteLast(value);
            }
            else//if it's in the middle, neither first nor last
            {
                Snode *current = head;//traversing all nodes
                Snode *previous=new Snode();
                while(current->next=NULL)
                {
                    if(current->data==value)
                    {
                        previous->next = current->next;
                        delete current;
                    }
                    previous=current;
                    current=current->next;           
                }
            }
        }
        else if(temp->count > 1)
        {
            temp->count--;//decrease the count
        }
    }   
}
};

int main()
{
    //defining a mySet as a "set" type
    set mySet;

    //adding values to create nodes
    mySet.insert('c');
    mySet.insert('a');
    mySet.insert('a');
    mySet.insert('c');
    mySet.insert('c');

    //displaying nodes through "value count" format
    mySet.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your constructor, you first initialize `head` to `NULL`, and _then_, if it's not `NULL`, you iterate over it and delete everything it contains before setting it to `NULL`. Seems pretty round-about.

Comment: @alterigel so my destructor would be sth like:
~set()
{
        if(head != NULL)
 {
  Snode *temp = head;
  while (temp != NULL)
  {
   head = head->next;
   delete temp;
  }
 }
}
right? @RemyLebeau they're not doing the same thing`set` assigns values but `~set` travers+deletes nodes.

Comment: @Nitwit no, your `~set()` code is wrong. You are assigning `temp` only once, and then `delete`ing the same `Snode` on each iteration. You are not advancing `temp` through the list at all. The code you have in `set()` is what `~set()` should be doing instead, eg: `set() : head(NULL) {} ~set() { Snode *temp = head; while (temp) { Snode *next = temp->next; delete temp; temp = next; } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enumerate the nodes of the old list, allocating new nodes for copied data and adding them to the new list.  The best place to do that is in a copy constructor and copy assignment operator of the `set` class.

Also, your `set` class's default constructor is doing the work that your destructor should be doing. Which is not necessary as there is nothing to delete yet in the constructor. Your destructor is not iterating through the list correctly. The code you have in the default constructor is iterating correctly.  That code needs to be moved from the constructor to the destructor.

Your other `set` class methods are not implemented very efficiently (redundant searches of the list), or even correctly in some cases (completely wrong logic, memory leaks, etc).

Try something more like this instead:

```
struct Snode
{
    char data;
    int count;
    Snode *next = nullptr;
    Snode(char a, int c = 1) : data(a), count(c) {}
};

class set
{
private:
    Snode *head = nullptr;
    Snode *tail = nullptr;

    void append(char value, int count)
    {
        Snode *temp = new Snode(value, count);

        if (!head)
            head = temp;

        if (tail)
            tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }    

    void remove(Snode *node, Snode *previous)
    {
        if (previous)
            previous->next = node->next;

        if (head == node)
            head = node->next;

        if (tail == node)
            tail = previous;

        delete node;
    }

    void swap(set &other)
    {
        Snode *ptr = head;
        head = other.head;
        other.head = ptr;

        ptr = tail;
        tail = other.tail;
        other.tail = ptr;
    }

public:
    set() = default;

    set(const set &src)
    {
        Snode *temp = src.head;    
        while (temp)
        {
            append(temp->data, temp->count);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    set(set &&src)
    {
        src.swap(*this);
    }

    ~set()
    {
        Snode *temp = head;
        while (temp)
        {
            Snode *next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = next;
        }
    }

    set& operator=(const set &rhs)
    {
        if (&rhs != this)
        {
            set temp(rhs);
            temp.swap(*this);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    set& operator=(set &&rhs)
    {
        rhs.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    bool isAvailable(char value)
    {
        return (find(value) != nullptr);
    }

    Snode* find(char value, Snode **previous = nullptr)
    {
        if (previous)
            *previous = nullptr;

        Snode *temp = head;
        Snode *prev = nullptr;

        while (temp)
        {
            if (temp->data == value)
            {
                if (previous)
                    *previous = prev;
                return temp;
            }

            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    bool isFirst(char value)
    {
        return ((head) && (head->data == value));
    }

    bool isLast(char value)
    {
        return ((tail) && (tail->data == value));
    }

    void display()
    {
        Snode *temp = head;
        while (temp)
        {
            std::cout << temp->data << " " << temp->count << std::endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    void insert(char value)
    {
        Snode *temp = find(value);
        if (temp)
            temp->count += 1;
        else
            append(value, 1);
    }

    int count(char value)
    {
        Snode *temp = find(value);
        return (temp) ? temp->count : 0;
    }

    void deleteFirst()
    {
        if (head)
            remove(head, nullptr);
    }

    void deleteLast()
    {
        if (head)
        {
            Snode *last = head;
            Snode *previous = nullptr;

            while (last->next)
            {
                previous = last;
                last = last->next;
            }

            remove(last, previous);
        }
    }

    void remove(char value)
    {
        Snode *previous;
        Snode *temp = find(value, &previous);    
        if (temp)
        {
            if (temp->count > 1)
                temp->count -= 1;
            else
                remove(temp, previous);
        }
    }   
};
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    //defining a mySet as a "set" type
    set mySet;

    //adding values to create nodes
    mySet.insert('c');
    mySet.insert('a');
    mySet.insert('a');
    mySet.insert('c');
    mySet.insert('c');

    set myCopiedSet = mySet; // make a copy of the list

    //adding more values to create nodes
    myCopiedSet.insert('a');
    myCopiedSet.insert('b');
    myCopiedSet.insert('b');
    myCopiedSet.insert('c');

    //displaying nodes through "value count" format
    std::cout << "original:" << std::endl;
    mySet.display();    
    std::cout << "copy:" << std::endl;
    myCopiedSet.display();

    return 0;
}
```

You can simplify the `set` class a bit further if you use a double-linked list instead of a single-linked list:

```
struct Snode
{
    char data;
    int count;
    Snode *previous = nullptr;
    Snode *next = nullptr;
    Snode(char a, int c) : data(a), count(c) {}
};

class set
{
private:
    Snode *head = nullptr;
    Snode *tail = nullptr;

    void append(char value, int count)
    {
        Snode *temp = new Snode(value, count);

        if (!head)
            head = temp;

        if (tail)
        {
            temp->previous = tail;
            tail->next = temp;
        }
        tail = temp;
    }

    void remove(Snode *node)
    {
        if (node->previous)
            node->previous->next = node->next;

        if (node->next)
            node->next->previous = node->previous;

        if (head == node)
            head = node->next;

        if (tail == node)
            tail = node->previous;

        delete node;
    }

    void swap(set &other)
    {
        Snode *ptr = head;
        head = other.head;
        other.head = ptr;

        ptr = tail;
        tail = other.tail;
        other.tail = ptr;
    }

public:
    set() = default;

    set(const set &src)
    {
        Snode *temp = src.head;
        while (temp)
        {
            append(temp->data, temp->count);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    set(set &&src)
    {
        src.swap(*this);
    }

    ~set()
    {
        Snode *temp = head;
        while (temp)
        {
            Snode *next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = next;
        }
    }

    set& operator=(const set &rhs)
    {
        if (&rhs != this)
        {
            set temp(rhs);
            temp.swap(*this);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    set& operator=(set &&rhs)
    {
        rhs.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    bool isAvailable(char value)
    {
        return (find(value) != nullptr);
    }

    Snode* find(char value)
    {
        Snode *temp = head;    
        while (temp)
        {
            if (temp->data == value)
                return temp;    
            temp = temp->next;
        }    
        return nullptr;
    }

    bool isFirst(char value)
    {
        return ((head) && (head->data == value));
    }

    bool isLast(char value)
    {
        return ((tail) && (tail->data == value));
    }

    void display()
    {
        Snode *temp = head;
        while (temp)
        {
            std::cout << temp->data << " " << temp->count << std::endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    void insert(char value)
    {
        Snode *temp = find(value);
        if (temp)
            temp->count += 1;
        else
            append(value, 1);
    }

    int count(char value)
    {
        Snode *temp = find(value);
        return (temp) ? temp->count : 0;
    }

    void deleteFirst()
    {
        if (head)
            remove(head);
    }

    void deleteLast()
    {
        if (tail)
            remove(tail);
    }

    void remove(char value)
    {
        Snode *temp = find(value);
        if (temp)
        {
            if (temp->count > 1)
                temp->count -= 1;
            else
                remove(temp);
        }
    }   
};
```

In which case, you can greatly simplify the `set` class by using STL's `std::list` container instead, which is a standardized implementation of a double-linked list:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

struct Snode
{
    char data;
    int count;
};

class set
{
private:
    std::list<Snode> nodes;

    auto findValue(char value)
    {
        return std::find_if(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(),
            [=](const Snode &n){ return (n.data == value); }
        );
    }

public:
    bool isAvailable(char value)
    {
        return (find(value) != nullptr);
    }

    Snode* find(char value)
    {
        auto iter = findValue(value);
        if (iter != nodes.end())
            return &*iter;
        return nullptr;
    }

    bool isFirst(char value)
    {
        return ((!nodes.empty()) && (nodes.front().data == value));
    }

    bool isLast(char value)
    {
        return ((!nodes.empty()) && (nodes.back().data == value));
    }

    void display()
    {
        for (auto &n : nodes)
            std::cout << n.data << " " << n.count << std::endl;
    }

    void insert(char value)
    {
        Snode *temp = find(value);
        if (temp)
            temp->count += 1;
        else
            nodes.push_back(Snode{value, 1});
    }

    int count(char value)
    {
        Snode *temp = find(value);
        return (temp) ? temp->count : 0;
    }

    void deleteFirst()
    {
        if (!nodes.empty())
            nodes.pop_front();
    }

    void deleteLast()
    {
        if (!nodes.empty())
            nodes.pop_back();
    }

    void remove(char value)
    {
        auto iter = findValue(value);
        if (iter != nodes.end())
        {
            if (iter->count > 1)
                iter->count -= 1;
            else
                nodes.erase(iter);
        }
    }   
};
```

Comment: and also it just shows the last two entered data. e.g. "insert 'c' 2 times+insert 'j' 3 times+insert 'r' 1 time" the output is "j 3 \n r 1" it ignores 'c'

Comment: @Nitwit Nowhere in the examples I provided is there an `Snode(char, Snode*)` constructor. Are you making changes to the code I gave you? But yes, if you don't have a node to pass in, pass in `nullptr`. Or give the parameter a default value of `nullptr`. The examples I provided all work correctly, no inserts are ignored, all data is displayed, as expected. Even your `'c' 'j' 'r'` example works. See live demos of [example 1](https://ideone.com/6tZFTP), [example 2](https://ideone.com/ebU9V3), and [example 3](https://ideone.com/oWz7pP).

Comment: @Nitwit read about the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/). A temporary `set` is created via the copy constructor, and then the list pointers are swapped. The assignee obtains ownership of the copied list, and the temporary obtains ownership of the old list and will free it when the temporary is destroyed. It is a clean and exception-safe way to implement assignment operators for classes that have pointers to data.

Comment: Btw there's one tiny bug, imagine that i add 'j' twice and delete it twice, the expectation is that app wouldn't show anything about 'j' but it does. It shows a line with j->count but with no data, just a number

Comment: @Nitwit fixed. In the 1st example, the `find()` method wasn't setting the `prev` variable while looping, so `remove()` wasn't updating nodes correctly.